# Retrieving a document from Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have just gotten the login working on my app and now directly after I am trying to pull up the document for the user so I can display their name on the page.

```
email = loginemail.value;
    password = loginpassword.value;
    signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
            .then((userCredential) => {
            // Signed in 
            alert("Thanks for signing in!");
            const user = userCredential.user;
            
            useremail.innerHTML = user.uid;
            // ...
            })
        .catch((error) => {
            const errorCodelogin = error.code;
            const errorMessagelogin = error.message;
            createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
            .then((userCredential) => {
                alert("Looks like you're a new user - we created a new account for you!");
                const user = userCredential.user;
                // ...
            })
            .catch((error2) => {
                const errorCoderegister = error2.code;
                const errorMessageregister = error2.message;
                pagebody.innerHTML = errorMessagelogin + "<br /><br />" + errorMessageregister;
            });
        });         
        
    const docRef = doc(db, "users", useremail.innerHTML);
    const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

    if (docSnap.exists()) {
        console.log("Document data:", docSnap.data());
    } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
```

This last bit with the const docRef is straight from Firebase's docs, I just substituted in my table name and doc id.

It is kicking off this error in the console:

> Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but users has 1.

Comment: It looks like `useremail.innerHTML` doesn't have a value. `console.log(useremail.innerHTML)` right before you use its value, or set a breakpoint on that line and run in the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code that tries to load the document runs before the sign in has completed.

To prevent that, `await` its result instead of using `then()`.

```
const userCredential = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
// Signed in 
alert("Thanks for signing in!");
const user = userCredential.user;

useremail.innerHTML = user.uid;
    
const docRef = doc(db, "users", useremail.innerHTML);
const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

if (docSnap.exists()) {
    console.log("Document data:", docSnap.data());
} else {
    // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
    console.log("No such document!");
}
```

In general: don't mix `await` and then in your code until you're more familiar with asynchronous behavior. Until then, use one *or* the other, not both.

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem. Clearly I need to do some more reading about async. :)